# Internet Explorer 9 Unable to get value of the property error

Tags: javascript, variables

In the following code I get an error of:

`Unable to get value of the property 'deal_score_round_img': object is null or undefined`

The debugger reports the value of `jdeals[i]['deal_score_round_img']` as:

`"<img src=\"assets/deal_scores/80.gif\" width=\"40\" height=\"35\" />"`

The error occurs on the first line (typeof).

```
if(typeof(jdeals[i]['deal_score_round_img'])!="undefined")
{
    var nums = jdeals[i]['deal_score_round_img'].match(/([[0-9]+)/ig);
    t.deal_score = nums[0];//80
}
```

The purpose of the script is to extract "80" from the image string.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Woah, this is the first time I've seen typeof being used without a space between it and its operand, I thought you were trying to invoke a special typeof function for a second there!

Comment: Yes, people say I should use spaces more!

Comment: That doesn't look like what I was suggesting, that looks like GrailsGuy's solution, or you can add an answer yourself :)

Comment: I will ,6 minutes before I can though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that jdeals may be null or undefined, and if that is expected, you want to check it too:

```
if(typeof(jdeals[i])!="undefined" && 
    typeof(jdeals[i]['deal_score_round_img'])!="undefined")
```

Comment: Thank you! As jdeals is alwats an array I used  `if(typeof(jdeals)!="undefined")`